# Why are there no problems with Ajax on the desktop, but have on the phone?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

There is a button on the site, when you click on that button, new posts are loaded.Everything works fine on the desktop, but it breaks down on the phone.

> ```
> XHR failed loading: POST "https://test-5.vbbn.in/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php".
> send @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:4
> ajax @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:4
> n. @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:4
> (anonymous) @ (index):1732
> dispatch @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:3
> r.handle @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:3
> ```

```
    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_action_javascript' );

   function my_action_javascript() { ?>
     <script>
           jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
           var page = 2;
   
           var post_count = jQuery('#posts').data('count');
   
           var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php');?>"
                jQuery('#load_more').click(function () {
   
                    
                       var data = {
                           'action': 'my_action',
                           'page': page
                       };
   
   
                       jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                           jQuery('#posts').append(response);
   
                           if (post_count == page){
                               jQuery('#load_more').hide();
   
                           }
   
                           page++;
                       });
                });
           });
     </script> <?php
   }
   
   
   
   add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );
   
   function my_action() {
     $args = array(
       'post_type'   => 'post',
       'category_name'=> 'nouvelles',
       'paged' => $_POST['page'],
     );
   $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
   
     <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
   
         <?php 
       while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
```

Tried to add e.preventDefault, to avoid rebooting that does not write the POST then pass event to the function, but it shows that e.preventDefault is not a function.

Website - https://test-5.vbbn.in/
Hope for any help. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to hit an url using admin ajax. but url is not returning 200 as response. It is returning 400(not found) . I just tested the url by clicking button. Please see the screenshot below that I attached.[image]

Now fix the issue and be confirm that your action is available for admin-ajax

Comment: Can you tell me how to give access to admin-ajax.php, because when I login, everything works?

Comment: But a new problem has appeared, the script for closing the banner for some reason works after 10-15 seconds on the phone (

Comment: can you share link?